# Set max height of UITableView

Tags: ios, swift

on the iPhone 5s it seems as though the last item of a specific list shown using UITableView goes slightly off screen and unable to select. Is their any simple way to prevent the tableview from displaying contents offscreen besides checking overtime data is reloaded and the current height of the view?

EDIT: This is all done programmatically and all other tableviews display correctly on the 5s I have tried fiddling with constraints but could not see a difference.

Comment: Do you mean you are unable to scroll the tableview to the bottommost element?

Comment: more so the the last element is cut off by the bottom of the screen. This only shows up on the dimensions of iphone 5 though

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your issue has to do with constraints. I'm not sure whether you're using a storyboard to build the view or not, but probably what you need to do is constrain the table view to the bottom of its superview.

Comment: ah i figured it had something to do with constrains I will look into it more since i am doing it programatically

Comment: You can do it programmatically. Check out NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithVisualFormat: